# PowerShell ConvertTo-XML Error

Tags: xml, arrays, powershell

I'm using PowerShell v3 on a Windows 8 system and can't find any good resources online to explain this problem I'm encountering. I have the following script:

```
$CIMProperty = Get-CimInstance win32_OperatingSystem
$OS = [PSCustomObject]@{
  Caption = $CIMProperty.Caption
  InstallDate = $CIMProperty.InstallDate
  }

$Asset = [PSCustomObject]@{
  Name = "TSZ"
  OperatingSystem = $OS
  }

$Asset | ConvertTo-Xml
```

and when I run it I get the following error:

> ConvertTo-Xml : Unexpected end of file has occurred. 
>   The following
>   elements are not closed: Objects. Line 9, position
>   12. At C:\Users\Ben\SkyDrive\Documents\Scripting\Inventory\Troubleshooting-Compact.ps1:12
>   char:10
>   + $Asset | ConvertTo-Xml
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertTo-Xml], XmlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Xml.XmlException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToXmlCommand

I've done a bunch of testing and found that this only happens when I have more than one property for my $OS object. Defining the typename for each property didn't seem to help. If I use my own arrays of something like `$OS = "test","123"` there is no error.

If I set `$OS = Get-CimInstance win32_OperatingSystem` there is no error, and using Export-CliXml cmdlet also works. However I'm trying to produce a well-formatted `XML` document that needs minimal processing before being displayed in a custom XML viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try :

```
$Asset | ConvertTo-Xml -Depth 2
```

Comment: Ha! Look at that. I don't know why I didn't think to look at possible parameters more. I assumed the default depth was no max. May others one day learn from my noob mistake. Thank you!